# How to create a list which only adds letters that are unique to adjacent indices in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing, spyder

I have created a function which randomly generates a list of the letters "a", "b", "c", and "d". I would like to create a new list which is the same as the first list but with any letters/items which are the same as the previous letter/item removed. Where I am having problems is referring to the previous letter in the list.

For example, if :

`letterlist = ['a','a','a','b','b','a,',b']`

then the output should be,

`nondupelist = ['a','b','a','b']`

The problem is that nodupeletterlist is the same as letterlist - meaning it's not removing items which are the same as the last - because I am getting the function to refer to the previous item in letterlist wrong. I have tried using index and enumerate, but I am obviously using them wrong because I'm not getting the correct results. Below is my current attempt.

```
import random

def rdmlist(letterlist, nodupeletterlist):
    for item in range(20):
        rng = random.random()
        if rng < 0.25:
            letterlist.append("a")
        elif 0.25 <= rng and rng < 0.5:
            letterlist.append("b")
        elif 0.5 <= rng and rng < 0.75:
            letterlist.append("c")
        else:
            letterlist.append("d")
    for letter in letterlist:
        if letter != letterlist[letterlist.index(letter)-1]:
            nodupeletterlist.append(letter)
        else:
            pass
    return

letterlist1 = []
nodupeletterlist1 = []
rdmlist(letterlist1, nodupeletterlist1)
```

EDIT:
This is what I ended up using. I used this solution simply because I understand how it works. The answers below may provide more succinct or pythonic solutions.

```
    for index, letter in enumerate(letterlist, start=0):
        if 0 == index:
            nodupeletterlist.append(letter)
        else:
            pass
    for index, letter in enumerate(letterlist[1:], start = 1):
        if letter != letterlist[index-1]:
            nodupeletterlist.append(letter)
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: Could you provide your sample input and output and what is going wrong?

Comment: There isn't a sample input/output, rdmlist creates a new list of letters each time it's ran. The problem is that the noduperletterlist created should be the same as the letterlist created but with any items which are the same as the previous item in letterlist removed; instead what is happening is that noduperletterlist and letterlist are the same.

Comment: @DarelHalgarth,you want to remove duplicate items from the list?

Comment: Your "working solution" fails if the first and last element of the list are the same, since in the first step of the iteration you compare the first letter to the letter at index `0-1`, which is `-1` and hence the last letter. Just try it for `['a', 'b', 'b', 'a']`, it returns `['b', 'a']`, not `['a', 'b', 'a']`. Unless you intend this to wrap-around, this is wrong.

Comment: You can fix your solution by filling the `nodupeletterlist` with the first character first, and running your iteration on `letters[1:]`, similar to my proposed solution. Also, use `start=1` in the `enumerate`.

Comment: This doesn't append the first letter in the list. I will just write something to append the first letter in the list though.

Comment: @DarelHalgarth I added a fixed version of your "working solution" to my answer. I'd appreciate it if you upvote and accept, since so far there are no other working solutions for this.

Comment: I'll review this tomorrow, I have to sleep now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import itertools

nodupeletterlist = [k for k, _ in itertools.groupby(letterlist)]
```

---

Solution without using `itertools`, as requested in the comments:

```
def nodupe(letters):
    if not letters:
        return []
    r = [letters[0]]
    for ch in letters[1:]:
        if ch != r[-1]:
            r.append(ch)
    return r

nodupeletterlist = nodupe(letterlist)
```

---

A fixed version of the proposed "working solution":

```
def nodupe(letters):
    if not letters:
        return []
    r = [letters[0]]
    r += [l for i, l in enumerate(letters[1:]) if l != letters[i]]
    return r

nodupeletterlist = nodupe(letterlist)
```

---

You can also simplify your random generator a bit, by using [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices):

```
import random

chars = 'abcd'
letterlist = random.choices(chars, k=20)
```

or by using [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint):

```
import random

start, end = ord('a'), ord('d')
letterlist = [chr(random.randint(start, end)) for _ in range(20)]
```

Comment: I'd rather use avoid importing if there is a solution which doesn't require it. I do appreciate you simplifying my random letter generator though, I didn't know about random.choice.

Comment: Since both `random` and `itertools` modules are part of the standard library, those should be available everywhere, except maybe for specialized custom Python installations. But I see  your point. Does it solve your problem, though?

Comment: I can't make it work, but I may have done something wrong. I am getting the following error: "AttributeError: module 'itertools' has no attribute 'grouby".

Comment: Oh, damn, it's a typo, fixed it. I also added a non-`itertools` solution.

Comment: `k for k, _` had me confused for a minute there. @JanChristophTerasa figured it out though.

Comment: @Todd It's conventional to use underscores for iteration variables you are not going to use, e.g. in this case I unpack the tuple, but do not use the second member. One can also write `x[0] for x in ...`.

Comment: yeah.. I know the convention. Just haven't seen it in a while.

Comment: The itertools solutions works, albeit separately from the rdmlist function. I can't immediately figure out how to implement the non-itertools correctly, and I'm not going to spend time trying to figure it out - sorry - since I now have solutions which work as part of my existing function. I really do appreciate the help though, my random letter generator is much simpler now.

Comment: @DarelHalgarth Please check my comment on your original question, your proposed correct solution is wrong. Also, what kind of problems do you have wih the non-itertools solution? You can just copy-and-paste as it is.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i, letter in enumerate(([None]+letterlist)[1:], 1):
    if letter != letterlist[i-1]:
        nodupeletterlist.append(letter)
```

Comment: This will miss the first letter group if it's a duplicated pair like `["a", "a", "b", "b"]` will end up being `["b"]` instead of `["a", "b"]`

Comment: This also deletes the first letter, but I tried changing it slightly and it appears to work without deleting the first letter.
```for index, letter in enumerate(letterlist):
if letter != letterlist[index-1]:
nodupeletterlist.append(letter)```

Comment: This ignores the first letter, i.e. gives the wrong result for `['a', 'b', 'b', 'a']`.

Comment: @DarelHalgarth You can create a dummy element as the first one, like `for i, letter in enumerate(([None]+letterlist)[1:], 1):`, then it should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with. Using `random.choices()` would be better than what I have below, but same idea. **doesn't involve itertools**

```
>>> li_1 = [random.choice("abcdefg") for i in range(20)]
>>> li_1
['c', 'e', 'e', 'g', 'b', 'd', 'b', 'g', 'd', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'e', 'c', 'd', 
 'e', 'e', 'f', 'd', 'd']
>>>
>>> li_2 = [li_1[i] for i in range(len(li_1)) 
...                                      if not i or i and li_1[i - 1] != li_1[i]]
>>> li_2
['c', 'e', 'g', 'b', 'd', 'b', 'g', 'd', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'e', 'c', 
 'd', 'e', 'f', 'd']
```

Comment: This ignores the first letter.

Comment: If you'd return the favour. :-)

Comment: Sure thing. I didn't downvote you btw - I just commented because the syntax was interesting to me.

Comment: I never thought you did. I also just downvote answers which are clearly wrong/not answering the question, and I will happily upvote if they do and are good/concise.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with the way that you are using `letterlist.index(letter)-1` is that `list.index(arg)` returns the the index of the first occurrence of `arg` in `list`, in this case the letter. This means that if you have `list = ["a", "b", "a"]` and you run `list.index("a")` it will always return 0.
A way to do what you intend to (removing consecutive repetitions of letters) would be:

```py
nodupeletterlist.append(letterlist[0])
for idx in range(1, len(letterlist)):
    if letterlist[idx] != letterlist[idx-1]:
        nodupeletterlist.append(letterlist[idx])
```

Comment: This does delete consecutive repetitions of letters, but it also deletes the first letter.

Comment: It doesn't, the first letter will always be added by `nodupeletterlist.append(letterlist[0])`.

Answer (score -2):

Do This:

```
L1 = ['a','a','a','b','b','c','d']
L2 = []
L2.append(L1[0])
for i in range(1,len(L1)):
    if L1[i] != L1[i-1]:
        L2.append(L1[i])
```

set() will create a set with only unique values,then the list() will convert it back to a a list containing values without any repetition.

I hope this helps...

Comment: This will only store each letter once, so for `['a', 'b' 'a', 'a', 'b']` it will return `['a', 'b']` instead of `['a', 'b', 'a', 'b']`.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa,from the problem I understood that the values should not repeat,That's why I proposed this solution...

Comment: to quote: "I would like to create a new list which is the same as the first list but with any letters/items which are the same as the previous letter/item removed."

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa,yea man I am trying to wrap my head around it too,but the thing is,if we remove the repeating elements,the two lists won't remain the same,plus there is no sample input/output given to work on:(